# improve performance of mutiply table join

Tags: sql, performance, join

I have a view derived from join of over 15 tables. The performance is so poor, since it has millions of records. It takes 3 hours to run it!!!
I am wonder if there is any way to improve the performance of this view. For example:

```
using subquery:
table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select table2.column2, table2.column2 
                 from table 2) as b 
      ON table1.column1 = b.column1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Table3.column1 from table3) 
      as c ON table1.column1 = talbe3.column1 ...
```

rather than using join:

```
table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
      ON table1.column1 = table2.column1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 
      ON table1.column1 = table3.column1 ...
```

Comment: c'mon man spend some effort formatting

Answer (score 0):

No return only a view columns via a derived table will not improve performance

I suggest you post the entire (properly formatted) query with query plan